# Fallos usando 'std::initializer_list' con 'const char*', 'const char *&' y 'std::string'

Tags: c++, template, c++17

Tengo un sencillo programa que usa una variable plantilla de tipo `std::initializer_list` que guarda pares que contienen un tipo y un texto:

```
using name_t = const char *;

template <typename key_t>
using key_name_t = std::pair<key_t, name_t>;

template <typename type_t>
std::initializer_list<key_name_t<type_t>> values;
```

La variable plantilla es inicializada mediante una plantilla variádica:

```
template <typename type_t, typename ... KV>
void init(type_t value, const char *name, KV ... kv)
{
    values<type_t> = {{value, name}};
}
```

Al darle uso:

```
int main()
{
    init(1, "uno", 2, "dos", 3, "tres");
    //             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- parámetros ignorados

    for (const auto &kv : values<int>)
        std::cout << kv.first << '\t' << kv.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Esperaba una salida como:

> ```
> 1    uno
> ```

Pero la salida es memoria aleatoria:

> ```
> -809605168
> ```

He pensado que tal vez el puntero dentro de `key_name_t` se esté perdiendo así que he cambiado `name_t`:

```
using name_t = const char *const &;
```

Uso referencia constante para aprovechar la [extensión del ciclo de vida](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) al asociarse con una referencia constante, pero entonces el código causa un `segmentation fault`, así que decido cambiar de nuevo `name_t` a alias de `std::string` y vuelvo a recibir `segmentation fault`.

---

El código completo:

```
#include <iostream>

using name_t = 
               //const char *;
               //const char *const &;
               std::string;

template <typename key_t>
using key_name_t = std::pair<key_t, name_t>;

template <typename type_t>
std::initializer_list<key_name_t<type_t>> values;

template <typename type_t, typename ... KV>
void init(type_t value, const char *name, KV ... kv)
{
    values<type_t> = {{value, name}};
}

int main()
{
    init(1, "uno", 2, "dos", 3, "tres");

    for (const auto &kv : values<int>)
        std::cout << kv.first << '\t' << kv.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Disponible en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/up0RJt129NLgt5j5)</kbd>.

- ¿Por qué estoy recibiendo esos `segmentation fault`?
- ¿Por qué la versión con `name_t = const char *` apunta a memoria no válida?.
- ¿De qué manera puedo conseguir un funcionamiento correcto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> Copying a std::initializer_list does not copy the underlying objects.

Así que yo no creo que la asignación que haces en `init` vaya a ser demasiado productiva. ¿La razón? cuando se abandona `init` la lista deja de ser válida porque el origen de datos ha sido eliminado.

De hecho si hacemos lo siguiente:

```
template <typename type_t, typename ... KV>
void init(type_t value, const char *name, KV ... kv)
{
    values<type_t> = {{value, name}};

    for (const auto &kv : values<int>)
        std::cout << kv.first << '\t' << kv.second << '\n';
}
```

Vemos como sí que muestra valores... pero la lista original, que es `{{value, name}}` (porque recordemos que en este punto no estamos inicializando la variable global sino haciendo una asignación) se va a destruir.

Otro ejemplo para controlar el ciclo de vida:

```
struct T
{
  T() { std::cout << "T::T()\n"; }
  T(T const&){std::cout << "T::T(const&)\n"; }
  ~T() {std::cout << "T::~T()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Init()\n";
    init(T{}, "uno", T{}, "dos", T{}, "tres");
  std::cout << "Fin Init()\n";
  std::cout.flush();
    for (const auto &kv : values<int>)
        std::cout << /* kv.first << */ '\t' << kv.second << '\n';

  std::cout.flush();

  return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
Init()
T::T()
T::T()
T::T()
T::T(const&)
T::~T()
T::~T()
T::~T()
T::~T()
Fin Init()
```

Se han destruido tantos objetos como se han creado... luego el bucle va a acceder a elementos que ya no están vivos.

Considera utilizar otro tipo de objeto diferente a `std::initializer_list`

Una posible solución:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using name_t = 
//const char *;
//const char *const &;
std::string;

template <typename key_t>
using key_name_t = std::map<key_t, name_t>;

template <typename type_t>
key_name_t<type_t> values;

template<class InsertIterator, class Type, class Value, class ... Args>
void FillContainer(InsertIterator iterator, Type type, Value value, Args... args)
{
  iterator = {type,value};

  if constexpr(sizeof...(args) > 1 )
    FillContainer(iterator,args...);
}

template <class type_t, typename ... KV>
void init(type_t value, const char *name, KV ... kv)
{
  FillContainer(std::inserter(values<type_t>,values<type_t>.end()),value,name,kv...);
}

int main()
{
    init(1, "uno", 2, "dos", 3, "tres");

    for (const auto &kv : values<int>)
        std::cout << kv.first << '\t' << kv.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UJ1YgDamWyxUB4dg)</kbd>